# can't see categories in appearance-menu-categories

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, functions

I have a php script that takes categories from softonic.com.
It is supposed to insert these categories inside an apps category. It does it with wordpress functions. 
After launch my script I can see all the categories inserted in the database, and also in the post-categories menu as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

But my problem is I need to do the menu navigation, and when I go to appeareance menu - categories I should see this:

[image]

but I see this:

[image]

And there are hundreds of categories. I can't do my navigation menu. 
I should see the categories under a tree, but they show in alphabetical order and without parents. As you can see in the first image, they have all a parent. How can I see them like in the second image??
I'm inserting it with this function and it worked before:

```
    $id = wp_create_category($cat_name, $parent );
```

but I have this problem since I have upgraded my shaifa theme.

Comment: And if you switch theme to a bundled one (a Twenty-something one) do you see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is [normal behaviour](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen). Quoting the codex:

> The list of categories to select from do not display with any
>   hierarchy, though that may be subject to change in future versions of
>   WordPress.

As far as I'm aware there is no plugin for this either.